# use arabic-reshaperin and bidi for convert a text in py (convert from file)

Tags: python, arabic

i need to use reshaperin And bidi in python for convert some arabic Text

my question is how can i use arabic-reshaper for convert text inside of a txt file and save converted text in other txt file

its my code for convert one line

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
text = 'سلام محمد خوبی'

test = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
print(get_display(test))
```

i know its a easy question But I haven't worked with Python until today
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible using a list

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
text = 'سلام محمد خوبی'
test = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
print(get_display(test))
lines = []

with open("file.txt", encoding="utf8") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(arabic_reshaper.reshape(line))

#Save it to file with a line break
with open("file2.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as output: #created if it doesnt exist
    for line in lines:
        output.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: I apologize for bothering you again
but can you merge your code with this?
`import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
text = 'سلام محمد خوبی'

test = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
print(get_display(test))`
as i said im not good at python syntax

Comment: Completed. I would advise you to practice python, see here https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/

Comment: you will need to replace `file.txt` with your filename

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue. Updated the answer

Comment: It works fine on my IDE. I have updated again with encoding for writing to the file. I would advise you to use an IDe to run this and it should work

Comment: Pycharm is my preference. Install and run and it should work. if this answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: You are not using the updated code my friend. Use the exact one above :)